# Generic linked list

Tags: java, generics, linked-list, nodes

So for my class I have to write my own linked list. Which I mostly understand, but the teacher wrote the mynode class

```
public class MyNode<E extends Comparable<E>> {
        E element;
        MyNode<E> next;

    public MyNode(E item) {
    element = item;
    next = null;
    }
}
```

And we are meant to make a class to run with it and have it run this program

```
public class TestLinkedList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyLinkedList<String> L = new MyLinkedList<String>();
    L.add("Browns");
    L.add("Ravens");
    L.add("Steelers");
    L.add("Bengals");
    L.add("Chargers");
    System.out.println(L);
    System.out.println(L.find("Ravens") ? "Found Ravens" : "Did not find Ravens");
    System.out.println(L.find("Giants") ? "Found Giants"
            : "Did not find Giants");
    L.insertElementBefore("Steelers", "Colts");
    L.delete("Chargers");
    System.out.println("Result after deleting Chargers: " + L);
}

}
```

But I don't understand why node is extending comparable.  I've found plenty of examples where node is just node E but none like this and I am just stumped on how to use this to write my linkedlist.

Comment: Is that to do with the `MyLinkedList.find()` implementation? Does that method use the Comparable interface?

Comment: Generally you extend comparable when you want to have compare actions on your list. Since the MyNode object is user defined, Java cannot easily compare them.

For example: Java knows how to compare a 'larger than' for numbers. It knows 5 is larger than 3 but how will it know that MyNodeA is larger than MyNode B.

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial of why you would extend the comparable interface - http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang/how-to-use-comparable-interface.html

Answer (score 3):

First things first: Node is **not** extending Comparable, the type `E` of the Node class is extending Comparable.

The generic bound `<E extends Comparable<E>>` is a "self-referencing" bound and means the type `E` implements the `Comparable<E>` interface, which has the method `int compareTo(E e)`.

The usual reason you deal with Comparable objects is so you can sort them - in java parlance, they have a *natural sorting order*.

You task is to implement the various methods called on the MyLinkedList class. If the methods called from the sample code are the only methods, there is no reason that the generic type  of `MyNode` needs to be `Comparable` - ie `MyNode<E>` would be fine.

Comment: I would like to use MyNode without comparable, as this is an example already defined several times. But my teacher is making me use it and I'm trying to make a linked list containing nodes but confused about how the nodes work or even what to do with them. Is each node meant to hold one value or what? I need to make a add method that functions like adding a value to the Java linked list and a find remove and one to insert it before an element I believe a to string method but once I understand the rest it shouldn't be a problem

Comment: You would only need the value to be Comparable if either the nodes were Comparable (and you would delegate the comparison of nodes to comparison of their values) or you wanted to build a Comparator for nodes (similar approach). Unless one of those were stated reasons, it's a design flaw to make the value be Comparable. Yes, each node has one value. Your node class should also have a reference ("link") to the next node in the list, and methods for adding, inserting. The methods will be recursive, calling the same method of the next link until `this` link is the right link to perform the action.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I still have had no luck. I can't edit the node class or the main class. I've been turning to make an array of nodes but when I do system.out.println(l) I get mylinkedlist@ and then the memory location. Hopefully I can talk to my professor before it's due, I see now way to do so

Comment: I can link you to the assignment if you think that might help understand what I need to do

Answer (score 2):

The idea of Comparable is to make the Nodes easy to compare. On a technical level, it imposes a total order: there's an unambiguous ordering of non-equal objects (Less-than-or-equal-to is an example of an operator that imposes a total order). As nEm points out in comments, Java doesn't know what it means for one object to be "less than" another object, unlike with integers; that's what `compareTo` (The method exposed by the Comparable interface) is for.

Without knowing the full interface for your linked list implementation, it's impossible to say where this will be useful. Some educated guesses include the `Node.insertElementBefore` function, or a `Node.find`, if you're required to implement that.